# iPhone 3GS wont mount

Tags: mount, iphone, error-handling

I cant mount my iPhone. I've mounted my iPhone before with the same cord and it worked just fine.

This is what it said:

[image]

I ran `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` while the iPhone was plugged in, and this is what it said:

[image]

I also ran `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while the iPhone was plugged in and it said:

[image]

Comment: Can you run `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` and then connect your iphone? Paste the output into your question by [edit]ing it. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like either nothing went into your dmesg when you connected your phone, or you didn't grab the dmesg output from connecting your phone.  At any rate, thanks for persisting with this.  If you do manage to get something in dmesg *while* you connect your phone, post it, or if there is anything interesting in, say, `/var/log/syslog` (eg replace dmesg with syslog).

Comment: Does anybody know what the problem is?